# Запись из поля timestamp в date

Tags: mysql, дата, update, timestamp

Есть два поля в `mysql` один типа `timestamp` другой `date`.
Как перенести (обновить) правильно из поля `timestamp` в поле `date`. Так чтобы записалось в формате `Y-m-d`.
Условно таблица `Dates` поля `id` (int), `public_date` (date), `date` (timestamp).

Запись

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id |    public_date      |         date        |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |        NULL         |  2017-2-18 11:11:11 |
|  2 |        NULL         |  2017-5-18 11:11:11 |
|  3 |        NULL         |  2017-2-12 11:11:11 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Должно обновится в

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id |    public_date      |         date        |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |  2017-2-18 11:11:11 |  2017-2-18 11:11:11 |
|  2 |  2017-5-18 11:11:11 |  2017-5-18 11:11:11 |
|  3 |  2017-2-12 11:11:11 |  2017-2-12 11:11:11 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Среди разных функций](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) обработки даты и времени есть подходящая функция `date`:

```
update tablename set date_field = date(timestamp_field);
```

Для условной таблицы соответственно:

```
update `Dates` set public_date = date(`date`);
```

Comment: #1292 - Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'public_date' at row 1

Comment: Совершенно логично на невалидную дату отвечать ошибкой. С переменным успехом (в зависимости от sql_mode настройки) давать ошибку на невалидные данные умеет даже mysql.

Comment: Это ошибка в поле date? Или как это исправить?